# MongoDB shows timeout error when connected with flask over docker

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, flask

I've been trying to connect flask with mongodb over docker but constantly get the timeout error. Here's my code and error below. Please let me know where I've gone wrong? Thanks.

Also, I've intentionally chosen port 27018 instead of 27017

app.py code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(host="test_mongodb",
                     port = 27018,
                     username = "root",
                     password = "rootpassword",
                     authSource = "admin"
                    )

#db is same as directory created to identify database
#default port is 27017

db = client.aNewDB
#db is a new database 
UserNum = db["UserNum"]
#UserNum is a new Collection
UserNum.insert_one({'num_of_users':0})
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: ./Web
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
    links:
      - db #Web is dependent on db
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    hostname: test_mongodb
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 27018:27018
```

Error during docker-compose up:

```
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "app.py", line 21, in <module>
web_1  |     UserNum.insert_one({'num_of_users':0})
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 628, in insert_one
web_1  |     comment=comment,
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 562, in _insert_one
web_1  |     self.__database.client._retryable_write(acknowledged, _insert_command, session)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1447, in _retryable_write
web_1  |     with self._tmp_session(session) as s:
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
web_1  |     return next(self.gen)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1729, in _tmp_session
web_1  |     s = self._ensure_session(session)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1712, in _ensure_session
web_1  |     return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1657, in __start_session
web_1  |     self._topology._check_implicit_session_support()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 538, in _check_implicit_session_support
web_1  |     self._check_session_support()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 555, in _check_session_support
web_1  |     readable_server_selector, self.get_server_selection_timeout(), None
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 240, in _select_servers_loop
web_1  |     % (self._error_message(selector), timeout, self.description)
web_1  | pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: test_mongodb:27018: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 62fa0685c58c2b61f79ea52e, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('test_mongodb', 27018) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('test_mongodb:27018: timed out')>]>
flask_project_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: You set `port = 27018` but MongoDB typically listens on port 27017.  Connections between containers always use the "standard" port numbers and ignore any `ports:` that may be set.

Answer (score 0):

In docker-compose config file, ports means expose specified ports from container network to host network, it does not do anything to tell the mongodb container to serve at port 27018, therefore, the mongodb will still open the port at 27017 even you specified the port option, therefore, you should tell the mongodb container by using the `command` option.

Add this line `command: mongod --port 27018` into the db service, then it should be working.

like:

```yaml
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    hostname: test_mongodb
    command: mongod --port 27018
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 27018:27018
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the line `command: mongod --port 27018` but I still find the 
same error.


`web_1  | pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: test_mongodb:27018: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 62fa0e34957cbc76c9de89f7, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('test_mongodb', 27018) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('test_mongodb:27018: timed out')>]>`


Can you please let me know if I've missed out anything else? Thanks.